# No permission to delete files on Windows?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 2.0 on Windows 8.

My program exists to do some house-cleaning: it will scan a log folder for files of a certain type, containing a certian substring, before a certain date, and delete them using `File.delete` if they are determined to be of no use to me.

The problem comes from the fact that I always get a `Permission denied` error, *even if I run the Ruby program from an elevated command prompt*. I have Googled the problem and everyone says to just elevate the command prompt, but I *am*, and it's not changing anything. What gotchas have I missed?

```
Dir.glob('C:/Users/sarah_000/AppData/Roaming/ScanLog/*.log') do |f|
  file = File.open(f)
  if file.read[0..29].include? "success" and file.mtime < Time.new(2014,9,1) then
    File.delete(file)
  end
end
```

Comment: Make sure you are an administrator or have read and write permissions to that file

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action

Do you check this, is it going to help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another process might have an open handle to the file you are trying to delete.  Try creating an extra, dummy file in the same directory and see if you can delete that.  Try terminating any programs that might have the file open.

Actually I just noticed that your Ruby program has the file open.  Try closing the file with `.close` before deleting it.

Comment: Closing the file before deleting it solved the problem, thanks for the advice!

Comment: In general you should arrange to close file handles as soon as possible, and Ruby has a number of ways to do that.  In this case, something like `first_part = File.open(f) { |fi| fi.read(30) }` would probably work well.